# How to add path to PowerShell object in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

When calling `GetPathToCmd` below, I also want `powerShell` to consider some special directory - `c:\scripts` (passed as parameter). Is there a way to add that directory only to `powerShell`'s `PATH` (i.e. `$env:Path`), without changing the path variable of the whole running process?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string pathToCmd = GetPathToCmd("file-to-look-for.py", @"c:\scripts");
        Console.WriteLine(pathToCmd ?? "Not found");
    }

    static string GetPathToCmd(string cmd, string alsoLookIn) {
        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {
            // Anyway to add "alsoLookIn" to powerShell's path?

            powerShell.AddCommand("get-command")
                .AddArgument(new[] {$@".\{cmd}", cmd})
                .AddParameter("Type", new[] {"Application", "ExternalScript"})
                .AddParameter("ErrorAction", "Ignore")
                ;

            CommandInfo commandInfo = powerShell.Invoke<CommandInfo>().FirstOrDefault();
            return commandInfo?.Source;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the $env:Path. However, the moment you do something like the below ...

```
# Modify current environment path for this session
$Env:Path = "$Env:Path;SomeNewFolderPath"
```

… then that $Env:Path change is there for the life of the session. It goes away when you start a new session.

However, you can do this on the fly, ensuring you don't clobber your original path this way

```
# Capture the current path
$CurrentPath = $Env:Path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;...


# Modify current environment path before entering the code segment
$Env:Path = "$Env:Path;SomeNewFolderPath"


$Env:Path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;...;SomeNewFolderPath



# Modify current environment path after leaving the code segment
$Env:Path = $CurrentPath

$Env:Path
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;...
```

Comment: The question is how to do it in `C#`.